# Creating datetime series in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a recording with the start time (t0) and length of the recording (N). How do I create a time series vector (ts) in python for every 10s increments?

```
For example: 
t0 = 2017-06-12T11:05:10.00
N=1000
So there should be an array of 100 (N/10)values such that: 
ts = [2017-06-12T11:05:10.00, 2017-06-12T11:05:20.00,2017-06-12T11:05:30.00 and so on...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module of Python.
First you need to convert your string into a date with `dateteime.strptime`:

```
t0 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-06-12T11:05:10.00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00")
```

where the `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00"` part is the description of your string format (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

Then you can increment a `datetime` object by adding a `timedelta` to it. Build a sequence like this:

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
ts = [t0 + i*delta for i in range(N)]
```

You can also recover dates as strings by using `datetime.strftime` with a similar syntax to `strptime`.

The whole thing would look like

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00"
t0 = datetime.strptime("2017-06-12T11:05:10.00", date_format)
delta = timedelta(seconds=10)
ts = [datetime.strftime(t0 + i * delta, date_format) for i in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np

t0=datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 12, 11, 5, 10)
dt=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
ts=np.arange(100)*dt+t0
```

There might be some easier way. I've never tried to find one. But this is how I do it.

Comment: the last line of the code throws an exception.

Comment: @lroth  Indeed typo (I don't know how it happens, since, as far as I remember, I copied/pasted from my python console). It was saying ``ts=np.arange(100)*ts+t0`` which is defining ts from ts. It now says ``ts=np.arange(100)*dt+t0``. Which makes more sense. That just means ``np.array([t0, t0+dt, t0+2*dt, t0+3*dt, ....])``